# MsMpEng.exe high CPU usage on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, anti-virus

We have a Windows Server 2012 installation that we use as an internal web server. Most HTTP requests are very slow on this machine (about 15 seconds for a simple ASP.NET WebAPI request). We noticed that during a request, the process `MsMpEng.exe`'s CPU usage is going to 50-90%.

`MsMpEng.exe` is Microsoft's Anti-Malware executable, included in Windows Defender, Forefront and Security Essentials. However, none of those products is installed on our server.

**Where can we configure the Anti-Malware component of Windows Server 2012?**

Comment: start -> type defender. Any luck with that?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any Defender entry there.. If I enter `Defender` and press `Enter`, Windows Search shows `No results found for your search`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We analyzed the problem with Sysinternals [ProcessMonitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), where we saw that `MsMpEng.exe` consumes much CPU time analyzing the log files of our web application (written by NLog).

Since we could not find a GUI to exclude the log files from `MsMpEng.exe`'s real-time monitoring, we added it using `regedit.exe`.

The solution was to create a DWORD entry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths`
```

where the key of the entry is set to the full path of our log files (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapp\logs`), and leaving the DWORD value at `0x00000000`.

Comment: This is an old answer and we already got UI for this: Start menu --> Virus & thread protection --> Manage settings -> Add or remote exclusions. Also it is possible to provide exclusions with policy editor.

Comment: Nice answer, and I forgot about the powerful Sysinternals tools. I edited your answer to add the official link.

Comment: @RomanR. I can't find Start menu --> Virus & thread protection --> Manage settings -> Add or remote exclusions on my windows 2012. Are you sure?

Comment: How did you manage to find which files "MsMpEng.exe" is trying to scan? I'd like to make exclusions as well :(

Answer (score 3):

You might find it under Endpoint Protection or System Center Endpoint Protection, there you can set excluded filetypes and such under settings.